# How to remove the setting button on Gnome Menu?

Tags: 18.04

How to remove the setting button (the first one)?
It's quite useless and I dont know how to search about it.

[image: here is the photo]

Thanks

Comment: you mean the first one among 4? it is called settings button not the keyboard-setting button.. are you talking about this button in Question?

Comment: Indeed, whether you consider quick access to "Settings" from that place useless is rather subjective. Probably it will take an extension to change that, like you already did adding the Suspend button. Short of that, you will need to edit the javascript code of Gnome Shell. Maybe not worth the hassle.

Comment: @PRATAP : yes, I want to remove that one, thank for your info,

@ vanadium (sr I cannot tag 2 people) : thanks

Comment: as vanadium commented y0u need to concentrate 0n java script which is very hard..